# Convert list of string representations of lists of strings of floats separated by spaces to list of lists of integers

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['['0.' '1.' '0.']', 
 '['1.' '0.' '0.']', ....,
 '['0.' '1.' '1.']']
```

I would like to have it look like this in Python:

```
[[0, 1, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1]]
```

I can't figure it out using strip(), split() and ast.literal_eval(). Thanks!

Comment: Your original list is illegal. Please check quotation marks and commas.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ["['0.' '1.' '0.']", "['1.' '0.' '0.']", "['0.' '1.' '1.']"]
new_data = [map(int, list(eval(re.sub("\.", '', i))[0])) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Solution without eval:

```
s = ["['0.' '1.' '0.']", "['1.' '0.' '0.']", "['0.' '1.' '1.']"]
new_data = [map(int, re.findall("\d+", i[1:-1])) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: `i.replace(".","")` is always cheaper and faster than `re.sub("\.", '', i)`. And you should _never_ use `eval`: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html